# How do I put a fixed-position element on top of a relative positioned element?

Tags: html, css, position, fixed, overlap

Is it even possible?  I made a header for my site position at "fixed". The i also have an image positioned at "relative". Whenever I scroll the site.... I noticed that the image was layered "above" the header. Even the twitter profile widget i placed was above the header. They both overlap the header and i dont want that. Any  idea on how to resolve my problem? please HELP!

Btw.... ive heard that "fixed" is buggy esp in Android, where I am making my site.

Comment: I added CSS to your tags

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use z-index to set the layering, something like this:

```
.menu {position:fixed; z-index:99999}
.content {position:relative; z-index:1}
```

Then you can fine tune it by using numbers in between.